# Why the layout is not being displayed like in the image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I want to have a layout structure like in the image, where the "Header" text is aligned at the center and the link aligned at the right and in the left column I have some text and below each text, an image aligned at the center:

[image]

But it's not working properly, I'm trying to get this layout like this "https://jsfiddle.net/e2gvbjyq" but there are 3 issues:

- the link "Link" is not properly vertically aligned with the "Header" text and is not properly aligned at right
- the images in the left column are not aligned at the center like in the image above
- the `padding:1em` in the right column is not having any effect on the column
- the footer doesn't appear at the bottom like in the image above

Do you know why? I'm a beginner so I'm trying to use the basics like margin, float to achieve this layout.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </header>

    <section id="content-left">
      <article>
        <h2>Left Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae officiis neque atque amet fugit, eveniet at maxime nesciunt. Sint repellat neque necessitatibus ea sequi tempora, dolor non, possimus magni odio</p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">


        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae officiis neque atque amet fugit, eveniet at maxime nesciunt. Sint repellat neque necessitatibus ea sequi tempora, dolor non, possimus magni odio.</p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">


        <p class="issue"><b>(Issue: Images are not aligned at center)</b></p>

      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="content-right">
      <article>
        <h2>Right Title</h2>
        <p class="issue">(Issue: padding left is not working)</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
      <p><b class="issue">(Issue: footer is not at bottom of the page)</b></p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    border:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
}

h2{
    font-size: 80%;
}

h3{
    font-size: 75%;
}

header{
    background-color: #cc9;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

header h1{
    display: inline;
}

header a{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}

header a:hover{
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #cc9;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}


article{
    padding:1em;
    text-align: left;
}

article p{
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
    font-size: 70%;
}

article img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px;
}

#content-left{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 1em;
}

#content-right{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1em;
}

.issue{color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra div and make it flex.

Header width:100%
 content-right: width:50%
 content-left: width:50%
 Footer width:100%

```
  <body>
<div class="conteiner">
    <header>
    <section id="content-right">
    <section id="content-left">
    <footer>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
.conteiner{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Link to your code:
https://codepen.io/Vova_Champion_1/pen/JjdqbLr

Comment: Thanks, but like that is also not working properly. For example here "https://jsfiddle.net/e2gvbjyq/1" the link in the header is not appearing only in the header it appears in the header but also in the right content section. Also, the content of the right content section is appearing on the left content section.

Comment: First, you forgot to add  #container{ display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;} in your code. Second you forgot to add  #content-right{width: 50%;}, and last your Link has height higher than header, so remove from header a{ line-height: 30px;} or make your header higher. https://codepen.io/Vova_Champion_1/pen/JjdqbLr

Comment: Thanks, do you know why the article img is not aligned at center? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cwrmpf05/

Comment: I know, just remove tag "article" (NOT article img {}, YES img {} ). I didn't find "article" in your HTML. If my answer works for you, please accept it.